# Meteor method vs. deny/allow rules

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In Meteor, when should I prefer a [method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/methods) over a `deny` rule?

It seems to me that `allow`/`deny` rules should be favoured, as their goal is more explicit, and one knows where to look for them.

However, in the Discover Meteor book, preventing duplicate insertions (“duplicate” being defined as adding a document whose `url` property is already defined in some other document of the same collection) is said to have to be defined through a method (and left as an exercise to the reader, chapter 8.3).

I think I am able to implement this check in a way that I find much clearer:

```
Posts.deny({
    update: function(userId, post, fieldNames, modifier) {
        return Posts.findOne({ url: modifier.$set.url, _id: { $ne: post._id } });
    }
});
```

*(N.B. if you know the example, yes, I voluntarily left out the “only a subset of the attributes is modified” check from the question to be more specific.)*

I understand that there are other [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) than `$set` in Mongo, but they look typed and I don't feel like leaving a security hole open.

So: are there any flaws in my `deny` rule? Independently, should I favour a method? What would I gain from it? What would I lose?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Normally I try to avoid subjective answers, but this is a really important debate. First I'd recommend reading [Meteor Methods vs Client-Side Operations](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/) from the Discover Meteor blog. Note that at Edthena we exclusively use methods for reasons which should become evident.

## Methods

### pro

- Methods can correctly enforce schema and validation rules of arbitrary complexity without the need of an outside library. Side note - [check](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check_package) is an excellent tool for validating the structure of your inputs.
- Each method is a single source of truth in your application. If you create a 'posts.insert' method, you can easily ensure it is the only way in your app to insert posts.

### con

- Methods require an imperative style, and they tend to be verbose in relation to the number of validations required for an operation.

---

## Client-side Operations

### pro

- `allow`/`deny` has a simple declarative style.

### con

- Validating schema and permissions on an `update` operation is infinitely hard. If you need to enforce a schema you'll need to use an outside library like [collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2). This reason alone should give you pause.
- Modifications can be spread all over your application. Therefore, it may be tricky to identify why a particular database operation happened.

---

## Summary

In my opinion, `allow`/`deny` is more aesthetically pleasing, however it's fundamental weakness is in enforcing permissions (particularly on updates). I would recommend client-side operations in cases where:

- Your codebase is relatively small - so it's easy to grep for all instances where a particular modifier occurs.
- You don't have many developers - so you don't need to all agree that there is one and only one way to insert into *X* collection.
- You have simple permission rules - e.g. only the owner of a document can modify any aspect of it.

In my opinion, using client-side operations is a reasonable choice when building an [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product), but I'd switch to methods for all other situations.

---

**update 2/22/15**

Sashko Stubailo created a [proposal to replace allow/deny with insert/update/remove methods](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Proposal-to-replace-allowdeny-with-insertupdateremove-methods-1WCvv4P9e2h).

**update 6/1/16**

The meteor guide takes the position that `allow/deny` [should always be avoided](http://guide.meteor.com/security.html#allow-deny).

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot. Not accepting immediately to leave room for other possible answers. One question though: why do you call allow/deny rules “client-side operations”? Indeed, they can be simulated, but AFAIK are also executed on the server (it would be pretty insecure otherwise). Perhaps is it just a matter of phrasing, as in opposition to methods which are purely server-side (even if they can be stubbed), but it could be misleading to a less-informed reader.

Comment: The choice is between using an [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) (a method) or directly mutating the database from untrusted code (a client-side operation). allow/deny rules are simply the mechanism required to make client-side operations work.

Comment: “When a client calls insert, update, or remove on a collection, the collection's allow and deny callbacks are called **on the server** to determine if the write should be allowed.” — [source](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow). It would be totally useless otherwise  ;)

Comment: That's correct. The server-defined allow/deny rules make db operations on the client possible. The client modifies the db and sometime later the allow/deny rules and run on the server to determine if the operation should be accepted. If they fail (or don't exist), the operation is reversed on the client. I can't tell if you are agreeing with my previous statements or trying to make a new point. :)

Comment: Well, I was disagreeing  ;)  But I guess that was a misinterpretation. I read “mutating database from untrusted code” as something potentially dangerous, which it is not if the only possible consequence is for the client to change its own database. My earlier point was: calling rules “client-side” reads as if it was client-only, which it isn't  :)

Comment: Yes, I can see why that phrasing was confusing. Maybe "client initiated modifications" is more clear - alas, I did not coin the phrase. Side note - "untrusted code" is meteor-speak for any code which does not run on the server (e.g. client code).

Comment: I have a question about this guys... I am starting to build my app, and for me, Methods are more appealing, in the same direction this answer is going.
But I am wondering... if you only use methods... are you loosing the "reactivity" from Meteor? Or there is some mechanism to make methods "reactive"?

Comment: They are both reactive in the sense that they modify the underlying database and those changes will be propagated to the client. I think what you are asking about, however, is latency compensation. For that I'd recommend reading [this](https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-latency-compensation) and [this](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/advanced-latency-compensation/). In short, you can get the same LC results with methods if you write them with that in mind.