# Mongo collection undefined on Meteor front-end

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have this code on my front-end, yet PlayersList is undefined in the browser:

//client/allowHelpers.js

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

    PLayersList.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  }
    });   
});
```

(PlayersList var is undefined in the code block above.)

But it is defined in my Meteor lib directory, where I have this setup.js file containing both server/client JavaScript:

//lib/setup.js

```
  PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection("PlayersList");

  if(Meteor.isServer){
             Meteor.publish('thePlayers', function(){
             var currentUserId = this.userId;
             return PlayersList.find({createdBy: currentUserId})

             });

          PlayersList.allow({
               insert: function (userId, doc) {
                 return true;
          }
        });

          PlayersList.before.update(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
           console.log('about to insert:',userId,doc,fieldNames,modifier,options);
        });

          PlayersList.before.insert(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
            console.log('about to insert:',userId,doc,fieldNames,modifier,options);
        });

            PlayersList.after.insert(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
            console.log('just inserted:',userId,doc,fieldNames,modifier,options);
        });

    Meteor.methods({

        sendLogMessage: function(msg){
          console.log("Message from server:" + msg);
        },

        insertPlayerData: function(playerName){

            var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();

            PlayersList.insert({
               name: playerName,
               score: 0,
               createdBy: currentUserId
          });
        },

          removePlayerData: function(selectedPlayer){
             PlayersList.remove(selectedPlayer);
           }
        });
}

if(Meteor.isClient){
    Meteor.subscribe('thePlayers');
    Meteor.subscribe("PlayersList");
}
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: is your html have setup.js file above allowHelpers.js?

Comment: yes setup.js is in the top-level lib directory, and allowHelpers.js is in the client directory

Comment: if you run on console `PlayersList.find().fetch()` what do you get?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: PLayersList is not definedallowHelpers.js?5ee90adad01a23572be97c050a2ca461d638a7a7:5 (anonymous function)startup_client.js:30 runStartupCallbacksstartup_client.js:32 ready

Comment: PlayersList is definitely defined in the browser console, if I run PlayersList.find().fetch() - but I still get the error above

Answer (score 1):

You have the allow on the client side,just move the allow to server code.

```
 PLayersList.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
      return true;
      }
    });
```

**NOTE:**

In this case you are using a meteor.method to make an insert

```
PlayersList.insert({
               name: playerName,
               score: 0,
               createdBy: currentUserId
          });
```

You need to know that Meteor.methods skips the allows/deny (ignored them), so there is not reason for have the allows here(if you are only using this PlayerLists.insert)

So just delete the allow inside the client code.

or move it into the the server side.

Take a look into this [awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330321/meteor-method-vs-deny-allow-rules) from @david Weldon if you have doubts about using `Allows/deny` or `server methods`

Comment: this.userId or just userId?

Comment: Well just for theist purposes try using putting this on the publish function `console.log(currentUserId)`

Comment: check answer update you are using allow on client code, also you have both PlayersList.allow defined on the server.

Comment: should MongoCollection.allow be on the server, the client, or both?

Comment: still working on this one - obviously the problem disappears if I just delete the PlayersList.allow code on the client, because that code block was the only thing giving me an undefined on the client