# Meteor publish data of current user

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to publish only the data created by the logged-in user.  I have the following `publish` function:

```
    //server/collections/lists.js

    Meteor.publish('lists', function(){
        if(this.userId){
            return listCollection.find({createdBy: this.userId});
        } else {
            this.ready();
        }
    });
```

but when I go to create a document as a logged-in user, the place on the DOM where the template should be rendered 'flashes' with the document Ive created, but then it disappears.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

This is a symptom of attempting to insert on the client, not having an [allow rule](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) for the insert, and then having the insert rejected by the server a moment later. Try adding something like this under your `server` directory:

```
listCollection.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
    return (userId && doc.owner === userId);
  }
});
```

Note that you will need to customize the rule for your particular use case (e.g. you may not have an `owner` field). For example, you could just `return userId` to allow inserts from any logged in user.

Alternatively, you could not set up the `allow` and instead use a [method](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) to perform the insert. Generally speaking, that is my recommendation - see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330321/meteor-method-vs-deny-allow-rules).

Comment: is `createdBy` a Meteor convention, or must that field be defined on the collection?  I got it from a snippet of a tutorial

Comment: You can call it whatever you like. I believe `owner` is more common, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: but to be clear, Im adding the field `owner` in my `listCollection = new Meteor.Collection('listCollection')` definition and having it `return Meteor.userId()`  ?

Comment: No, not unless you are using a package to manage your schema. Your collection definition should just be `listCollection = new Meteor.Collection('listCollection')`. The collection doesn't know about it's own schema - that's up to the allow/deny or methods to enforce. I'd recommend going through the [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/install) to see these things in action.