# .deny Meteor use.. can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, meteor, permissions

I'm trying to deny a question to be submitted if it has a length of 0. But I don't quite understand Meteor deny.

Here's what's going on.

I am updating the question. It is currently set at "yes"

I update it to "yessir"

I console log it as follows:

```
Questions.deny({
  update: function(userId, question) {
    console.log(question.question.length);
   }
});
```

but the result is 3. It seems to console log the field being updated, not what I am updating it TO.

This is a problem because how can I check the length of an input if this thing won't check it when it's being submitted.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) and you'll see that the 2nd argument to `update` is `doc`:

> doc is the current version of the document from the database, without the proposed update

The only way to validate the length of `question` is to look at the 4th argument - `modifier`. The problem with this approach is that you must check the modifier for **every possible way** it could be modified. Fundamentally, this is why allow/deny is really hard to implement in all but the most simple cases.

Instead, I'd strongly suggest either using [collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) to enforce your schema or using methods to modify your documents.

Recommended reading:

- [Meteor method vs. deny/allow rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330321/meteor-method-vs-deny-allow-rules)
- [Allow & Deny: A Security Primer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330321/meteor-method-vs-deny-allow-rules)

Comment: Posts.deny({
  update: function(userId, post, fieldNames) {
    // may only edit the following two fields:
    return (_.without(fieldNames, 'url', 'title').length > 0);
  }
});

Comment: this is from a tutorial I'm following, but it seems that for them it does evaluate the current parameter that will get updated? do you know How could I do the same?

Comment: You need to look at `modifier` - I'd recommend console logging it.  You'll need to do something like `var value = modifier.$set.question; if (value.length > 3) {...}`. But again, what sucks about this is you are assuming `$set` is how `question` is updated... what if it's modified a different way? In short you are doing something that allow/deny simply wasn't designed for.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection.deny` Function either returns `true` or `flase`.
If you want to deny update on certain criteria here goes your code like this

```
Questions.deny({
update: function(userId, question, fields, modifier) {
// check for critera
if(fields.question.length < 0)
return true // denys update for question length less than 0
else
return false // deny = false means allow = true

}
});
```

Comment: This isn't correct because `question` doesn't contain the proposed update - this is fundamentally what's being asked.

Comment: what I'm saying is that I can't evaluate current criteria being updated. I will only evaulate the current question, not the content of the updated question.