# How to allow only certain document fields to be inserted and updated in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, security, meteor

I'm using Meteor, and I'm concerned about a possible security hole.  I only want users to be able to create modify certain fields in the database.  For this example, the only thing I want them to be able to create or update are `name` and `description` fields for a party.

```
Parties.allow({
  insert: function (userId, party) {
    return userId && party.owner === userId;
  },
  update: function (userId, party, fields, modifier) {
    return userId && party.owner === userId;
  },
});
```

This is the code I saw in the Angular Meteor tutorial, but it looks like someone could add any fields they wanted in the console on the browser, using Minimongo.  Is there a way I can easily define fields that are OK, and deny all inserts and updates that don't use those fields?  I could write a simple function that does that for updates:

```
function ensureFieldsAreOk(acceptableFields,fieldsInQuestion){
    for(i = 0; i < fieldsInQuestion.length; ++i){
        if(acceptableFields.indexOf(fieldsInQuestion[i]) === -1){
           console.log("Hacking attempt detected");
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

To do this for the insert command I could use the same function using `Object.keys(party)` as the acceptable fields list.

I can't imagine I'm the first person to think of this; there must be a standard way of dealing with this.

Comment: Alternatively, you could consider [using a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330321/meteor-method-vs-deny-allow-rules) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the fields that are associated with a collection you could use https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/simple-schema and https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/collection2

You get to define, fields, their types, default values and a lot of other options.

As for making sure a user can update only specific fields, you could do the check with the fieldNames attribute in the update allow/deny rules:

```
update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) { 
    // check fieldNames here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with doing it that way, and I don't know of any way that would be more proper. You can reduce your test quite a bit though using underscore:

```
Parties.allow({
  insert: function (userId, party) {
    return userId && party.owner === userId 
           && _.difference(_.keys(party), acceptableFields).length == 0;
  },
  update: function (userId, party, fields, modifier) {
    return userId && party.owner === userId
           && _.difference(fields, acceptableFields).length == 0
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, your question is completely valid. The way that I handle this in my Meteor applications is to screen the document that is either being inserted or updated. The approach that I take for insert and update is different due to the difference in parameters that are passed to the `insert` and `update` permissions functions.

I would suggest using the following code directly or something similar to suit any additional needs that you may have based on your criteria specified above:

```
Parties.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        var allow = true;

        if(!userId || doc.owner !== userId) {
            allow = false;
        }

        Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(docKey) {
            if(acceptableFields.indexOf(docKey) < 0) {
                allow = false;
            }
        });

        return allow;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
        var allow = true;

        if(!userId || doc.owner !== userId) {
            allow = false;
        }

        fieldNames.forEach(function(fieldName) {
            if(acceptableFields.indexOf(fieldName) < 0) {
                allow = false;
            }
        });

        return allow;
    }
});
```

As you can see in the code sample, I have included your check for whether or not the user is logged in and whether or not the user is the owner of the document that they are attempting to insert into or update in the database. Also, the `insert` function checks the document's keys directly (obviously, you could do a more thorough check if you had to check keys deeper than the top-level keys like my code example) and fails the allow if any are not contained within the list of acceptable fields. For the `update` function, since the `doc` parameter is the unaltered document, you need to check the `fieldNames` parameter instead. As with the `insert` function, if you need to perform a more thorough check for keys deeper than the top-level keys, you could directly check the `modifier` parameter and dig out every single key referenced in the insert attempt. For all of the information that you might need to determine how your final solution will look, take a look at [this section](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) of the Meteor documentation.

Finally, I wrote my answer using generic Javascript in case that is the route you would like to take. Obviously, you could use libraries like Underscore and others to enhance my suggestion.