# Meteor: Building admin frontend to manage users - delay in showing data

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to create a little admin frontend on which I can display a list of all users and to edit user-data (like roles). 
So what I did so far is to create a new publication (allUsers) and create methods for displaying and changeing the roles of the user:

**shared/collections.js**

```
Users = Meteor.users;
```

**server.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'updateRole': function(userId, role, value) {
        if (value) Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, role);
        else Roles.removeUsersFromRoles(userId, role);
        return userId;
    },
    'loadRoles': function(userId, role) {
        var result = { role: role, value: Roles.userIsInRole(userId, role) };
        return result;
    }
});

Meteor.publish('allUsers', function(){
    return Users.find();
});
```

**router.js**

```
Router.route('/users', {
    name: 'users',
    waitOn: function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
    },
    data: function() {
         return {
            users: Users.find({})
         }
    }
});

Router.route('/user/:_id', {
    name: 'userEdit',
    waitOn: function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
        Session.set("userEditId", this.params._id);
    },
    data: function () {
        return { 
            users: Users.findOne({ _id: this.params._id })
        };
    }
});
```

**client.js**

```
Template.userEdit.onRendered(function() {
    var role,
        userId = Session.get("userEditId"),
        elements = document.getElementById('formRoles').elements;

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var dom = elements[i];
        if(dom.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') {
            role = dom.getAttribute('name');
            Meteor.call('loadRoles', userId, role, function (error, result) {
                $("input[name=" + result.role + "]").prop('checked', result.value);
            });
        }
    }
});

Template.userEdit.events({
    'change input[type="checkbox"]': function(event) {
        var userId = document.getElementById('formRoles').getAttribute('data-id'),
            role = event.target.getAttribute('name');
            value = event.target.checked,

        Meteor.call('updateRole', userId, role, value, function (error, result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
});
```

**template**

```
<template name="users">
    <ul class="list">
        {{#each users}}
            <li><a href="/userEdit/{{_id}}">{{profile.name}}, {{profile.surname}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="userEdit">
    <h1>{{users.profile.name}}, {{users.profile.surname}}</h1>
    {{#if isInRole 'admin'}}
        <form id="formRoles" data-id="{{users._id}}">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="admin"> Administrator</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="role2"> Role</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="role3"> Role</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="role4"> Role</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="role5"> Role</label>
        </form>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

**Update**

This is how I display all users in a list and display all roles of a selected user. The problem is, that the display works in two steps with a delay: 
That means, when the page is loaded, first there is just one user and after a second all other users are added to the list. Same to a userEdit: First I just see "," and after a second it is filled to "Name, Firstname".

Can somebody explain this behaviour to me? And how can I improve the code to avoid these two steps?

Because of the "two-step-display", I think I wrote the code much to complicated...

**Update 2**

I think the delay results from the subscription of allUsers in the route-waitOn. Is it possible to improve that?

Comment: I'd do updates to users via a Meteor call

Comment: @user3142695 well modifying a user's own profile works strangely, but modifying the properties of another user works the same as any other collection. You just need a method, or a set of allow/deny rules. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330321/meteor-method-vs-deny-allow-rules) for a comparison. An answer could be added for this question if you indicate how you want to update the collection.

Comment: @DavidWeldon I updated my code I wrote so far. But I don't understand the delay in displaying and this causes a problem for loading. Please have a look at the updated post.