# Inserting data to collection via template event: security issue and callback necessary?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I got two questions for inserting some data by using a change event for a template:

1. Is this a proper way to insert new data as I'm thinking of security issues? Or do I have to create a method on the server?
2. I would think that the insert takes some time, so the `newElementId` isn't available immediatly. Correct? So think I do need a kind of callback. This would depend on the answer of the first question: If I have to put the `insert()` on server side, I have to do send the new ID to the client for the `Route.go`

**event**

```
Template.createElement.events({
    'change input': function(event, template) {
        var collection = event.target.value,
            route      = event.target.dataset.route
            title      = 'Title';

        newElementId = window[collection].insert({ title: title }, function(error) { if(error) console.warn(error); });
        Router.go(route, { _id : newElementId });
    }
});
```

Comment: The answer depends on if you want to allow db modifications from the client. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330321/meteor-method-vs-deny-allow-rules) for an overview of the differences.

Comment: Wouldn't a change event on an input potentially fire several times. e.g., if the user enters "duckbilled platypus" in an input element, your event will fire 19 times, first capturing and inserting "d" as the event.target.value, then "du", then "duc" etc.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon No, change fires on enter/blur of the input field. So if you are typing, it doesn't fire multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert or use a Method.Call

server side for both of those you can control the security.

If you go the insert route, then the item will be instantly in your collection, and it will sync with the server ( the server could reject it, then it will be removed from the client as well)

If you go the Method.call, it will insert on the server first, then by synched back to the client. So it might show up a little later than the first method.  I tend to find this method a more robust way of controlling security and for doing partial updates.

You don't need any callbacks, everything should update reactively.

Comment: Method.call route also allows for instant client side updates - define the method so it's visible on both the client (which will simulate the call  -  i.e. latency compression), or if necessary define a separate client stub method.

Comment: But I still don't understand one thing: If I do a method.call, this will take a little time. But on the next line of the client-side code there will be done a route.go. Is there no problem as the new ID created by the server method could be undefined in the moment the router.go is called?

Comment: in that instant, its generating client side, so it generates a unique id , then goes to the route.... that unique id will be inserted into the db ( if it allows it )