# In Meteor.js, what's the difference between method-based database API design and the subclass approach?

Tags: meteor

Namely, what are the advantages and disadvantages of the following approaches to building a server-side database API in Meteor?

1. Method-based

   ```
   import Db from 'Db';
   Meteor.method({"insert": (data) => {Db.insert(data)});
   ```
2. Subclass-based

   ```
   import {Mongo} from "meteor/mongo";
   class MyCollcetion extends Mongo.Collection {
       insert: (data) => {super.insert(data);}
   }
   ```

---

This problem has been solved below; there is a similar question for further reading: [Meteor method vs. deny/allow rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330321/meteor-method-vs-deny-allow-rules#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly a matter of ease vs control. Subclassing may be easier for simple things, and methods are more powerful.

This can also be affected by your state of mind (or affect it): CRUD vs. action-based mutation.

`insert`/`update`/`remove` go well with a CRUD state-of-mind, while you can associate methods with action-centric RPC mutators.

Eventually, this is a matter of personal preference, so I will try to give a short factual description and let the readers to decide based on their taste.

## Subclassing

By default, Meteor **automatically generates** mutation methods (`insert`, `update`, `remove`) when a collection is instantiated.

Those methods are called behind the scenes when calling `MyCollection.insert(mutator, cb)` on the client side (outside client-side method code). When arriving to the server, the data are first passed through **allow/deny rules** and then executed.

When subclassing, you override those methods and **get a 'hook'** into the process.

## Using methods

When defining a Meteor method you get **full control** of the process.

You set the parameters and the name of the method and you can **perform the validation and authorization** as you wish.

You can also create a **method stub** for client-side use, which generates optimistic UI until the results of the method server execution are received.

You can use something like a [`validatedMethod`](https://github.com/meteor/validated-method) to get some extra validation logic and modularity to your method.

You can also prevent the creation of the default mutation methods by setting a `false` value for the [`defineMutationMethods`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection) option when instantiating the collection. You can also forbid direct mutation from the client by supplying the appropriate `deny` rules.

While subclassing allows you to use `MyCollection.insert(...)`, etc. on the client, you need to call the method name with the arguments that you defined in order to mutate data.

Comment: Cheers. May I ask you one more question: Can the client-side mutate the database once the `insecure` package is removed? If that's true then methods is the only way to access the database.

Comment: That depends on the allow/deny rules. I think that the `insecure` package is not a very good idea for anything other than a throw-away prototype.

Comment: Just realized that I said the opposite of what I wanted to say. I meant "If that's false then methods is the only way to access the database. " I agree that the `insecure` package should be removed, indeed I removed it from the very beginning. Thanks for confirming that allow/deny rules are the guards to database mutation from the client.

Comment: My statement still holds :) The ability to "directly" (i.e, by using the same syntax) mutate the database from the client side depends on the allow/deny rules.

Comment: Yes, I somehow confused you but I got your idea. Cheers!